# Do operators which admit non-orthonormal spectral expansions have any non-basis eigenvectors?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and $A:X\rightarrow X$ be an operator which admits a non-orthonormal basis $\{e_j\}_{j=0}^\infty$ of eigenvectors. Is it true that if $Ax = \lambda x, \ x \in X$ then $x$ is an element of $\{e_j\}_{j=0}^\infty$?

(As far as I know, the spectral theorem does not apply to a non-orthonormal basis, though I may be wrong).

I believe the answer is 'Yes' but my proof is quite long. It seems like this would be a pretty standard result if true.

Comment: Isn't  $Ax=\lambda x$ the definition of an eigenvector?

Comment: @user2520938 indeed it is. I made a typo.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a non-orthonormal basis"? Are you referring to a Riesz-basis? Or do you mean a Schauder Basis?

Comment: @PhoemueX By a non-orthonormal basis, I mean a basis of the space which does not satisfy $(e_i,e_j) = \delta_{ij}$. I am interested in a special case in which the basis happens to be a Schauder basis, but do not necessarily see a reason to restrict it to that case.

Comment: Come to think of it, your claim is not even true (as stated) for an orthonormal basis. Take $A$ to be the identity operator. Then every (Nonzero) vector is an eigenvector, but not every vector is an element of your basis. What is probably true is that $x$ will be in the closed span of all those elements of the basis which have eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: @PhoemueX OK. That's a perfectly fine example. In case each element of the basis can be associated with a different eigenvalue, I believe your hypothesis and my result concur.

Comment: @SZN: to discuss an answer to your question, uniqueness (or not) of vector expansion in your "basis" is essential. And it is not possible to discuss that without a definition. So, what do you mean by "a non-orthonormal basis"?

Comment: @MartinArgerami how's this: let $\{e_j\}_{j=0}^\infty$ be a countable subset of a Hilbert space $X$ such that for all $x\in X$ there is a unique collection of scalars $\{a_j\}_{j=0}^\infty$ for which $x = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_je_j$, and $(e_i,e_j) = k_{ij}$ where $k_{ij} \neq \delta_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1):

With your definition of basis from the comment (i.e.,  a Schauder basis), the answer is trivial for the case where each $e_j$ is an eigenvector for a different eigenvalue $\lambda_j$. Indeed, for a fixed $k$ the equality $Ax=\lambda_k x$ reads
$$
\sum_j x_j \lambda_j e_j=\sum_j x_j\lambda_k e_j.
$$
By the uniqueness of representation the above equality forces $x_j\lambda_j=x_j\lambda_k$ for each $j$; so, if $j\ne k$ and $\lambda_j\ne\lambda_k$, we get $x_j=0$. Thus $x=x_ke_k$ (you cannot avoid multiples, as a multiple of an eigenvector is an eigenvector).